# Adding consonants to create an antonym

Tags: word, no-computers, word-property

This is an emotional word with 2 vowels

Starting with it create two words by adding 2 different consonants.

The two new words are antonyms of each other. See below. What is that word?  No programming please.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One little word is

> ire - an angry emotion

With the antonyms

> fire - to sack someone from their job
>  hire - to employ someone
>  [and another near antonym of fire (excite) is tire (bore)]

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Well done!

Comment: @hexomino - 8 seconds - to the wire!

Answer (score 22):

How about:

> ail  (trouble or afflict (someone) in mind or body)

And the antonyms are:

> jail (to imprison) and bail (to get out of prison)

Answer (score 12):

I have an example

The original word is

> Ire

And the antonyms are

> **F**ire and **H**ire